# Ubuntu 12.04 server install fails with debootstrap warning

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, debootstrap

Have made several attempts to download and create iso on CD and USB of 12.04 server 64-bit. Install attempts on a few different machines always hits several "Debootstrap Warning - "......deb file was corrupt" errors. iso passes MD5checksum

Comment: You'll have to be more detailed than that.  Such as what cd exactly, and what is the exact error?  Better yet, collect /var/log/syslog.

Comment: We have created a boot cd and usb stick to install Ubuntu 12.04 server (actually) 32-bit. During "Install the base system"- Debootstrap warning-Warning:file:///cdrom/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6_2.11.1-0ubuntu_i386.deb was corrupt

Comment: And what is the md5sum of that file?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and I solved it with workarround described here: http://cirrus.ucsd.edu/~pierce/fix_ubuntu_usb/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.